# android:onClick="openBrowser" doesn't work in XML

Tags: android, xml, onclick

The `android:onClick="openBrowser"` doesn't work when I clicked the text, however it work fine for other image such as Facebook, Twitter and Instagram. The link in valid and it can be clickable when I put the text below the image but doesn't when I change the position. Can anyone help me with this?

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/homepagel2"
    android:scaleType = "fitXY" />

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp">

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/logofacebook"
        android:tag="http://www.facebook.com"
        android:onClick="openBrowser"
        />

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/instagramlogo"
        android:tag="http://instagram/"
        android:onClick="openBrowser"
        />  

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/twitter"
        android:tag="https://twitter.com"
        android:onClick="openBrowser"
        />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginBottom="-90dp"
       android:textSize="25sp"
       android:text="@string/website"
       android:tag="http://www..../"
       android:onClick="openBrowser"
       android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: the best thing i can tell is open your browser with the specified url, EG:- `android:onClick="https://google.com"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `android:clickable="true"` to your TextView

Answer (score 1):

By default, `TextViews` aren't clickable. I am not sure that you can perform a `onClick` event by using this xml attribute on textview without `clickable` attribute. Then, you can try to add this attribute:

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Or should make a click listener as below:

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        openBrowser(v);
    }
});
```

with this view:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-90dp"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:text="@string/website"
    android:tag="http://www..../"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

The click listener will automatically make it clickable, then the previous attribute will be useless.

Comment: Thank you, the android:clickable="true" works for me :)

Comment: This is weird, i had the same issue, adding clickable to the textfield resolved the issue. But interesting part is, the onclick method is working in all the devices we tested except in Nexus 4 running in android 4.4

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:autoLink="all"
            android:text="@string/link_text_auto"
            />
```

source :http://android.okhelp.cz/linkify-text-link-url-in-textview-text-android-example/